# Properties of the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, inclusion-exclusion

**The problem:**
Let $A_1,A_2, \cdots A_k$ be orthogonal projections. Let $A = \sum_{i=1}^{k}A_i$. Now, 
If $A$ is also an orthogonal projection, then $A_iA_j=0,\forall i\neq j$.

**What i have done:**

Let $M = C(A) = \text{column space of $A$} $  and $M_i = C(A_i) = \text{column space of $A_i$} $

$$\implies rank(A) = trace(A) = trace(\sum_{i=1}^{k}A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{k}trace(A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{k}rank(A_i)$$
$$\implies \dim M = \sum_{i=1}^{k}\dim(M_i) \tag{a}$$

Also, 
$\because A = \sum_{i=1}^{k}A_i \implies M\subset M_1+M_2+\cdots +M_k$
$$\implies \dim(M) \le \sum_{i=1}^{k}\dim(M_i)-\sum_{i<j}\dim(M_i\cap M_j)+\sum_{i<j<l}\dim(M_i\cap M_j\cap M_l)+\cdots
\cdots+(-1)^{k+1} \dim(M_1\cap\cdots \cap M_k) \tag{b}$$

subtracting equation equation $(a)$ from inequality $(b)$, we get

$\sum_{i<j}\dim(M_i\cap M_j)-\sum_{i<j<l}\dim(M_i\cap M_j\cap M_l) \cdots+(-1)^{k}\dim(M_1\cap\cdots \cap M_k)\le 0$

**Now, from here, i need two results which look fairly obvious, but i am unable to prove them.**

Let $B_1, B_2, \cdots B_n$ be $n$ sets. Then,

$|B_1\cup B_2 \cup \cdots\cup B_n|$
$= \sum_{i}|B_i|-\sum_{i<j}|B_i\cap B_j| + \sum_{i<j<k}|B_i\cap B_j \cap B_k|+\cdots\cdots +(-1)^{n+1}|B_1\cap B_2 \cap \cdots \cap B_n|$

**The results that i need are:-**

1. $ \sum_{i<j}|B_i\cap B_j| - \sum_{i<j<k}|B_i\cap B_j \cap B_k|+\cdots +(-1)^{n}|B_1\cap B_2 \cap \cdots \cap B_n| \ge 0$
2. $\sum_{i<j}|B_i\cap B_j| - \sum_{i<j<k}|B_i\cap B_j \cap B_k|+\cdots +(-1)^{n}|B_1\cap B_2 \cap \cdots \cap B_n| = 0$
    if and only if $|B_i\cap B_j|=0, \forall i\ne j$

**How do i prove results $1$ and $2$. Are they even true??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first inequality follows from the formula stated just before the two questions, as
$$|B_1\cup B_2 \cup \cdots\cup B_n|\le \sum_{i}|B_i|$$
The second equality is equivalent to
$$|B_1\cup B_2 \cup \cdots\cup B_n|= \sum_{i}|B_i|$$
The equality holds if and only if the sets are pairwise disjoint.

I think the following provides a simpler way of solving the problem stated at the very beginnimg of the post.

For any orthogonal projection $P$ we have
$$\langle v,v\rangle \ge \langle Pv,v\rangle =\langle Pv,Pv\rangle \ge 0$$
Assume
$$A=\sum_{i=1}^kA_i$$ and $v=A_ju.$ Then
$$\langle v,v\rangle \ge \langle Av,v\rangle =\sum_{i=1}^k\langle A_iv,v\rangle \ge \langle A_jv,v\rangle =\langle v,v\rangle$$
Therefore $\langle A_iv,v\rangle =0$ for $i\neq j.$
Thus $A_iv=0,$ i.e.
$A_iA_ju=0$ for $i\neq j$ and any $u.$ Thus $A_iA_j=0$ for $i\neq j.$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your response, however, does not answer my question. Could you offer a hint for proving the two results I mentioned in my question above?

Comment: I have added an explanation of 1. and 2. basing on the formula you have stated before the questions.